# Bokeh: textInput on_change function on widget doesn't work as expected

Tags: bokeh

my short script looks like the following:

```
output_server('ts_sample.html')

count = 0
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    global count
    count = count + 1

textInput = TextInput(title="query_parameters", name='fcp_chp_id', value='fcp_chp_id')
textInput.on_change('value', update_title)

curdoc().add_root(textInput)
p = figure( width=800, height=650,title="ts_sample",x_axis_label='datetime' )
p.line(np.array(data['date_trunc'].values, dtype=np.datetime64), data['latitude'], legend="test")
p.xaxis[0].formatter=bkmodels.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(hours=["%F %T"]))
show(curdoc())
```

It works, when bokeh server(bokeh serve) is running and I got the plotting, but on_change callback doesn't work as expected.

Assumed the value of textInput should be the content/string in the input box, but I changed it multiple times but the callback function update_title is never called (the count global variable is always 0). So apparently the underlying textInput.value is not changed, how can I change value attr and trigger the on_change function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple `TextInput` example using a callback rather than `.on_change()`.  This might be more helpful for beginners like me than the OP. I very slightly modified the slider example from

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-model-property-events

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.models import TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.get('data');
        var f = cb_obj.get('value')
        x = data['x']
        y = data['y']
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.trigger('change');
    """)

#slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power", callback=callback)
#layout = vform(slider, plot)

text_input = TextInput(value="1", title="power", callback=callback)
layout = column(text_input, plot)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you .
After search,  the on_change function not working with bokeh 0.10 realease but with the upcoming version 0.11 .

From : https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/MyztWSef4tI

> If you are using the (new) Bokeh server in the latest dev builds, you can follow this example, for instance:
>   https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py

From : https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/PryxrZPX2QQ

> The server has recently been completely re-written from the ground up
>   and is faster, smaller/simpler, and much easier to use and deploy and
>   explain. The major PR was just merged into master, and will show up in
>   the upcoming 0.11 release in December

For download the dev version  : https://anaconda.org/bokeh/bokeh/files

Comment: @A Laurent  thx for the information, waiting for version 0.11

Answer (score 1):

I adapt the example, it may be helpful:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import TextInput
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.data;
        var f = cb_obj.value;
        x = data['x']
        y = data['y']
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.change.emit();
    """)

#slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power", callback=callback)
#layout = vform(slider, plot)

text_input = TextInput(value="1", title="power", callback=callback)
layout = column(text_input, plot)

show(layout)
```

Comment: this works as-expected in bokeh 1.4.0. example above does not